# Custom EditText in Android

Tags: android

When the app starts the `EditText` field must display a string of text. When the user taps the field the cursor must go to the end of the text and allow the user to delete it before he enters whatever text they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hint as answered by @Nilesh and then set an OnFocusChangedListener something like the code below.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focused) {
            if (focused){
                if (editText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
                    editText.setText(editText.getHint());
                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This works. But i just have two more doubts.
     1. The cursor when I tap must go to the end of the text
     2. Once I delete the text the hint must not show

Comment: I have edited the answer to answer your first doubt and as per the 2nd you need to add a TextChanged listener use something like editText.addOnTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher ....);

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

it it called `android:hint` property of edittext look below code

```
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Please enter Email Address"/>
```

Comment: But a hint will go away when clicking on the edittext.

Comment: than whats do you want